# Why doesn't os.chflags() work under Linux?

Tags: python-2.7, debian, posix

I'm using Python 2.7.9 under Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit. I just tried to change file attributes by calling **`os.chflags(path, mode)`**. In the Python docs there is an [article about the `os` interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) which says that this method is available in *Unix*, but it doesn't work for Linux. Python always throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lexer/py/epam/tests/main.py", line 43, in <module>
os.chflags(path_to_file(file_name), stat.SF_NOUNLINK)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'chflags'
```

There is an [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/969032) which was already raised for that a long time ago, but I still can't understand why `os.chflags()` doesn't do the `chattr` command's job. Could anybody elaborate it?

Comment: The linked bug on launchpad says that it is (apparently) a bug in the Python's OS feature test: "the configure check fails".

Comment: Can you show what  `os.__file__` says.

Comment: Did you accidentally define your own os module or something like that? This looks like an import/resolution error of some kind. Try it in the repl and see what happens.

Comment: @pvg That is where my comment is going.

Comment: @MikeMüller I'm sure you're right, if a bit more cryptic :)

Answer (score 5):

Linux does not provide the `chflags` syscall, so Python does not provide the wrapper `os.chflags()`.

The `chattr` command uses the code (`e2fsprogs-1.42.13`'s `lib/e2p/fsetflags.c`):

```
        fd = open (name, OPEN_FLAGS);
        if (fd == -1)
                return -1;
        f = (int) flags;
        r = ioctl (fd, EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS, &f);
        if (r == -1)
                save_errno = errno;
        close (fd);
```

to set the extended attributes for a file, so if you port that to Python (and use some C to extract the value for `EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS` from `ext2fs/ext2_fs.h`), you can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import fcntl
import os
import struct

# Taken from ext2fs/ext2_fs.h.
EXT2_IMMUTABLE_FL = 0x00000010
EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS = 0x40086602

fd = os.open('/var/tmp/testfile', os.O_RDWR)
f = struct.pack('i', EXT2_IMMUTABLE_FL)
fcntl.ioctl(fd, EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS, f);
os.close(fd)
```

Et voilà:

```
[tim@passepartout ~]$ lsattr /var/tmp/testfile
----i----------- /var/tmp/testfile
[tim@passepartout ~]$
```

But for all practical purposes it is probably much more prudent to execute `chattr(1)` as a child process than to turn the proof-of-concept above into something that runs reliably without maintenance.

Comment: My willing was just to set one of these attributes to a file: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.UF_IMMUTABLE)
and verify it works, but looks like it is impossible

Comment: For a 32-bit machine (such as armv7, which I'm working on) use `0x40046602` as the op for `ioctl` instead of `0x40086602`.