# Java how to delete a file that has the IMMUTABLE bit set

Tags: java

Working on a Java 8 project where I copy files from external sources. In one of these sources a file is set with the immutable bit flag.

In **OSX** this is set like so

```
sudo chflags schg /path/to/file
```

In **Linux**

```
chattr +i /path/to/file
```

I now need to delete the files that I have copied. I had been using Apache Commons IO to delete the directory like so,

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("/path/here"));
```

However this crashes out with a `java.io.IOException exception`.

Is there any **Cross Platform way** to delete these files? The process running is the owner of the file.

Comment: Did you try looking at class in `java.nio.file.attribute` ?
`chattr` is very much Linux-specific and some of its arguments are filesystem-specific, so I doubt Java has bindings to it. It's probably safer to provide your own implementation via shell commands.

Comment: Yes I did have a look at it. I did consider just shelling out but I wanted to have a cross platform method of dealing with this rather then having to implement a Linux/BSD/Windows layer to deal with it on multiple platforms.

Comment: Just my opinion and unsure whether it is applicable here, but I would avoid to deal with so low level things in Java. My advice is to use the relevant OS command (or a shell). For example using `chflags` it would be `chflags -R 0 /path/here`. Then you can use portable java code...

Comment: Not sure but will java nio2 file attribute help? http://andreinc.net/2013/12/05/java-7-nio-2-tutorial-file-attributes/

Comment: look at this project : https://github.com/jenkinsci/jna-posix

Comment: What do you mean by `files from external sources`? Maybe you can avoid to have this bit set upfront. e.g. when it is some archive do not restore them.

Comment: I do not control the external sources. I simply copy them across and process them. I am unable to control their setting of the immutable bit in any way.

Answer (score 23):

**Problem** : Since, we know that the file with **immutable attribute** set, cannot be deleted by any user. Even The root user cannot delete the following file.

Now, to be able to delete the file you have to remove the immutable attribute and then delete the file.

*Now, what you have to do is to apply the shell command through the code and remove the immutable attribute on the file.*

**As you have mentioned the cross platform issue**

So the basic algo would be

---

**Step 1:** Detect which OS you are using 
sample code would be:

```
private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0)
    //your code for windows OS.
else if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0)
    //your code for MAC OS.
else if(OS.indexOf("sunos") >= 0)
    //your code for Solaris OS
```

Note: *I haven't added code for checking all OS's. So have a look at them by yourself.*
**Step 2:** This step helps you solve the **Cross platform issue** 
Issue the appropriate shell command through `java.lang.Runtime.exec` to remove the immutable attribute of the file. 
Look at the [java.lang.Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)).

**java.lang.Runtime.exec**  : Through this, you supply the appropriate shell command for any underlying Environment, whether be MAC, Windows, Linux etc.

*sample code would be*

```
//if the OS detected is Linux then
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chattr -i /path/to/file");
//Play with the process as you would like to, using the documentation.
//else if the OS detected is OSX then : example to unlock in OSX
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chflags nouchg /path/to/file");
//Play with the process as you would like to, using the documentation.
//else if the OS detected is say Windows then : example to unlock in    Windows
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ATTRIB -s -h /path/to/file");
//-s -h are used to unlock and unhide (i dont the Antonym of hide :p ) the file in windows
//Play with the process as you would like to, using the documentation.
```

**Note:** To run other shell commands which include pipes you can use this kind of sample code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"csh","-c","cat /home/narek/pk.txt"});
```

**Step 3:** Use the same Runtime.exec() to check whether the immutable attribute has been removed or not, like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsattr /whateverPath");
//Play with the process to check whether the attribute is set or not, using the documentation.
```

**Step 4:** If Step3 is true|false, whatever the logic you apply, then Delete the file using your respective command again using the Runtime.exec().

***Thing is to have a look at the above linked documentation of java.lang.Runtime.exec and work with it.***

please, let me know whether it helped to some extent or not.

Comment: neat sol, i would only suggest executing the `un set` command immediatly after copying the file, so steps remaining: process and delete... smooth ;)

Comment: That's cool. Was thinking what to comment but then thought your comment is way cooler. :p @Yazan

Answer (score 14):

> Is there any Cross Platform way to delete these files?

Not that I was able to find. I had to adopt the obvious solution you already considered, the long way round:

- detect on which OS I'm running,
- issue the appropriate shell command to remove the immutable bit
- *Verify* that it has been removed.
- and finally delete (in my case, change) the file.

Actually a simpler, and lazier, shortcut would be:

- execute the unlocking command blindly for all the known binaries (`/usr/bin/chattr`, etc.), *with full path* to avoid possible security problems. They will all quickly fail except one; on e.g. Linux any call to `ATTRIB.EXE` or `chflags` will fail. If they *all* fail, the system is not supported.
- execute with the appropriate parameters the one binary that did not fail, or the corresponding check binary file (e.g., `lsattr` for `chattr`), to verify flag removal.
- *or* you can just try deleting the file, and catch `java.io.IOException`.

I started looking into what it was that `chattr` did, but it was immediately clear that there were several specialized, OS-specific system calls I would have needed to issue: so there was no real advantage over calling an external binary, except perhaps performance, but that wasn't an issue in my case.

Once one goes on the OS-specific (native) road, through either JNI or [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), on a Linux system it is a "simple" matter of invoking the [appropriate IOCTL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465756/setting-immutable-flag-using-ioctl-in-c).

Note that it is not enough to identify the OS, you also need to identify the *filesystem*, because on e.g. FAT32 filesystems or NTFS-3G FSs, the IOCTL will return an error (the flag is either not available at low level, or not (yet) supported by the IOSS intermediate driver).

The same problem exists in [Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176464/why-os-chflags-doesnt-work-under-linux), where at high level a OS independent call *is* supplied... but it does not work everywhere.