# Java Swing KeyBindings stop working only on Mac

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, macos-sierra

I'm working on a game using Swing and I'm using KeyBindings for input from the keyboard.

I'm having issues where the KeyBindings stop responding. It happens every time I run the application, but as far as I can tell, it's not when a certain chain of events occurs. The KeyBindings just stop receiving input from the keyboard. I also use mouse input, which continues to work, so I know it's not related to input in general.

Some things I've tried:

- made sure my object was not garbage collected
- looked for a certain reason the issue occurs (ex: after a certain amount of time, a certain key combination pressed), to which I could find none
- tried to use a `KeyListener` instead

None of these worked.

I then copied the project (without changing any code) to a windows machine, and after testing, I could not get the problem to occur once. I didn't paste code here because I'm 99% positive this is not related to my code, but related to the operating system it's running on.

Is this a problem with the macOS, or the JDK for Mac, or something else I don't know about?

I'm using JDK version 8 update 112, the computer is running macOS Sierra version 10.12.2.

It seems someone else had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085422/java-swing-key-adapter-stops-working-after-a-while) I now do, but they never got an answer.

**EDIT**

Here's a code example where the problem occurs:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

//an example of the problem where the keyboard stops receiving input randomly
public class ProblemExample extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int xPos = 200, yPos = 200;
    private boolean wKey, aKey, sKey, dKey;
    private BufferedImage image; //sprite

    public ProblemExample() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //makes the sprite a red square
        image = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        int[] redPixels = new int[50 * 50];
        for (int i = 0; i < redPixels.length; i++) {
            redPixels[i] = 0xffff0000;
        }
        image.setRGB(0, 0, 50, 50, redPixels, 0, 50);
        initializeKeys();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    //sets up Key Bindings
    private void initializeKeys() {
        final String W = "W",
                     A = "A", 
                     S = "S", 
                     D = "D",
                     PRESSED = "PRESSED",
                     RELEASED = "RELEASED";

        InputMap inputMap = this.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = this.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), W + PRESSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), A + PRESSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), S + PRESSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), D + PRESSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), W + RELEASED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), A + RELEASED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), S + RELEASED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), D + RELEASED);

        Action wActionPressed = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                wKey = true;
            }
        };
        Action aActionPressed = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                aKey = true;
            }
        };
        Action sActionPressed = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sKey = true;
            }
        };
        Action dActionPressed = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dKey = true;
            }
        };
        Action wActionReleased = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                wKey = false;
            }
        };
        Action aActionReleased = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                aKey = false;
            }
        };
        Action sActionReleased = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sKey = false;
            }
        };
        Action dActionReleased = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dKey = false;
            }
        };

        actionMap.put(W + PRESSED, wActionPressed);
        actionMap.put(A + PRESSED, aActionPressed);
        actionMap.put(S + PRESSED, sActionPressed);
        actionMap.put(D + PRESSED, dActionPressed);
        actionMap.put(W + RELEASED, wActionReleased);
        actionMap.put(A + RELEASED, aActionReleased);
        actionMap.put(S + RELEASED, sActionReleased);
        actionMap.put(D + RELEASED, dActionReleased);
    }

    public void loop() {
        if (wKey) yPos -= 5;
        if (aKey) xPos -= 5;
        if (sKey) yPos += 5;
        if (dKey) xPos += 5;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, xPos, yPos, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ProblemExample example = new ProblemExample();
                Timer timer = new Timer(60, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        example.loop();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like the user says that the problem was with the mac - _It is related with my mac thanks anyway. – user5637682 Dec 13 at 12:21_

Comment: I saw that, but unfortunately the user did not post a solution to the problem if they found one

Comment: Without your [mcve], how can anyone else reproduce your result?

Comment: What LAF are you using?  You could try changing it and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: I haven't changed the LAF, so I guess I'm using the default

Comment: @Jayfray I reproduced this problem on a mac with the Windows LAF using `System.getProperties().put("os.name", "Windows");`
            and `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");`

Comment: Is this [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172001) yours?

Comment: That bug report is not mine, but it looks like they're having the same problem I am. Thanks for finding that

Comment: Setting `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` makes it go away for me. Looks very like an OS related bug.

Comment: That seems to work for me, thank you very much! If you post an answer I can award you the bounty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***You might think this is a bug in MAC, while it is not Because MAC has the feature of secondary keys***.
 As you are the user of MAC, I hope you are aware of this feature. This feature might be the **the cause** of your problem.
**The Secondary key feature of MAC :**  is used where holding down a letter key will display variations of that letter, like holding down “u” to get “ü.” This comes in handy when spelling non-English words.
There’s a simple way to take control and change the behavior of long key presses to accommodate your needs.

Open the Terminal app and write:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Then restart any open app in which you want this setting to activate.

**REVERTING BACK:**  Just,simply add `true` in place of `false` to the previous command like this:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

**UPDATE:**

 You can speed up the rate of key repeats or decrease the delay before a held key starts repeating, by going to the System Preferences, and make changes under the keyboard header.

Comment: If I were to release this application and some users downloaded it on their Macs, would this be a problem for them? If so, can I disable this feature for them?

Comment: @kneedhelp Yes, you can. Use java.lang.Runtime.exec() to change the  setting to false, and then when your application exits, change the settings back to original(true). If you do not know how to use this, here is my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882808/java-how-to-delete-a-file-that-has-the-immutable-bit-set/41140860#41140860

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Tahir Hussain Mir suggest about changing the Mac key settings, I find the problem lies with the looping, it'd be more efficient to implement it in a event-driven way, I took the liberty to change your code a bit. Together with Hussain Mir suggest 's solution, it should solve your problem.

You could also handle key-repeating yourself, by e.g., starting a timer on key press and stoping it on key release, but then the key pressing behavior will differ between Windows and Mac, which isn't really the way you want to go.

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

//an example of the problem where the keyboard stops receiving input randomly
public class SOMacKeyBindings extends JPanel
{
    private BufferedImage image; //sprite
    private Point point = new Point(200, 200);
    private int steps = 5;

    private class KeyAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        private Runnable runnable;

        public KeyAction(Runnable runnable)
        {
            this.runnable = runnable;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }

    public SOMacKeyBindings()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //makes the sprite a red square
        image = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        int[] redPixels = new int[50 * 50];
        for (int i = 0; i < redPixels.length; i++)
        {
            redPixels[i] = 0xffff0000;
        }
        image.setRGB(0, 0, 50, 50, redPixels, 0, 50);
        initializeKeys();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    //sets up Key Bindings
    private void initializeKeys()
    {
        final String W = "W",
                A = "A",
                S = "S",
                D = "D",
                PRESSED = "PRESSED";

        InputMap inputMap = this.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = this.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), W + PRESSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), A + PRESSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), S + PRESSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), D + PRESSED);

        actionMap.put(W + PRESSED, new KeyAction(() -> { point.y -= steps; repaint(); }));
        actionMap.put(A + PRESSED, new KeyAction(() -> { point.x -= steps; repaint(); }));
        actionMap.put(S + PRESSED, new KeyAction(() -> { point.y += steps; repaint(); }));
        actionMap.put(D + PRESSED, new KeyAction(() -> { point.x += steps; repaint(); }));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, point.x, point.y, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SOMacKeyBindings());
    }
}
```