# Using chflags from the os module or dir_util from the distutils module results in an AttributeError (when run on a *nix platform)

Tags: python, file-io

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chflags) shows that `os.chflags` exists.

However executing the below code on a *nix platform results in an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chflags
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'chflags'
```

Likewise `distutils.dir_util` [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree) also results in an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why os.chflags() doesn't work under Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176464/why-os-chflags-doesnt-work-under-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may just be because your system does not provide the syscall for `chflags`.
This is also the case for me running Mint 18.1 and I get the same results than you do, for both python2 and python3.

BSD systems provide this function while others do not necessarily do.

Answer (score 0):

I am heaving the same issue with my Python 3.6.7. at my Ubuntu 18.04 box.
It is mentioned in https://bugs.python.org/issue31313. 
In short, Linux doesn't support chflags.
Linux uses chattr, sadly Python os module doesn't.